# Create a AllowEditRange conditional to a value on a column range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below which allow me to unprotect a sheet with an AllowEditRange, verify which rows of a range in column C has data on it and write the work "Ok" on column B in the rows where data was found in column C. The code also protects the sheet in the end returning to normal with my AllowEditRange but I need that the rows where the "Ok" was stamped are taken out of the AllowEditRange, blocking them for further edition. In other words I'm looking for a way to cancel these rows from the AllowEditRange or delete the range and create a new one excluding the rows with "Ok" in column B.
I'm trying to incorporate something like:

```
Dim aer As AllowEditRange
For Each aer In ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges
    aer.Delete

    If InStr(-1, cell.Value, "") <> 0 Then
        Set aer = workbook.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add("Edition", workbook.Range("A1:D4"))
        aer.Users.Add "Power Users", True
    End If
```

But it's not working no matter what I do. Any help?

```
Sub Test()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Maze"

Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range

lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cell In Range("C32:C70" & lastRow)

    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "") <> 0 Then
        cell.Offset(, -1).Value = "Ok"
    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Maze"

End Sub
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get an error? Also, in your `Test()`, you have `Range("C32:C70" & lastRow)` ...I believe you just mean `Range("C32:C" & lastRow)`, no?  Also, you can't do `workbook.Range()`, assuming `workbook` is a `Workbook` variable.  You need a *sheet* reference before a `Range` type, not workbook.

Answer (score 0):

As it was giving me a huge headache and consuming loads of time, I gave up of the AllowEditRanges and came up with a a work around. I just split the code in two and used the good old lock and unlock cells. I'm leaving the code below if anybody got decides to go for it too. Also, the code I came up with is very slow and after a couple of hours I decided to ask if anybody has a faster alternative.

```
Sub LockRow()

Dim rChk As Range, r1st As Range

Set r1st = Columns("B").Find(What:="Ok", _
after:=Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), _
LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, _
searchdirection:=xlNext)

If Not r1st Is Nothing Then 
Set rChk = r1st
Do
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Maze"
rChk.EntireRow.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Maze"
Set rChk = Columns("B").FindNext(after:=rChk)
Loop While rChk.Address <> r1st.Address 
End If

Set r1st = Nothing
Set rChk = Nothing

End Sub
```